# Updating the latest row for a user in an Oracle 11g database?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-update

My code is in this [sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/624ea6/5).

Creating the table

```
create table my_table ( pk number, created date, user_name varchar2(200), start_date date);

insert into my_table (pk, created,user_name) values (1, sysdate-1, 'bob');
insert into my_table (pk, created,user_name) values (2, sysdate-2, 'frank');
insert into my_table (pk, created,user_name) values (3, sysdate,'bob');
insert into my_table (pk, created,user_name) values (4, sysdate,'frank');
```

Updating:

```
update my_table
set start_date = sysdate
  from my_table
 where pk = ( select max(pk) from my_table where user_name = 'bob' );
```

SQLFiddle gives me this error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended : update my_table set start_date = sysdate from my_table where pk = ( select max(pk) from my_table where user_name = 'bob' )
```

But I'm sure I have a semicolon in there in the right place.

What gives? I'm quite new to SQL, and thought this would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `from` clause, you already have it at the top:

```
update my_table
set start_date = sysdate
 where pk = ( select max(pk) from my_table where user_name = 'bob' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `from`:

```
update my_table
    set start_date = sysdate
     where pk = ( select max(pk) from my_table where user_name = 'bob' );
```